# Memory leak with FindMaximum/Minimum inside of Module

Tags: bugs, scoping, memory

This is my first question here. I have to solve coupled first order ODE-s and find the maximum of a function which depends on the solution of the ODE. I have to do this calculation in large quantities, so I wrote a function to do the job, but quickly ran out of memory. I think, this might be a minimal working example:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
ClearMemory := Module[{}, Unprotect[In, Out];
   Clear[In, Out];
   Protect[In, Out];
   ClearSystemCache[];];
GetMemoryUse := 
  UnitConvert[Quantity[MemoryInUse[], "Bytes"], "Megabytes"] // N;
RunDE[ini_] := 
 NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == ini}, y, {x, 0, 10}]
sol = First@RunDE[1];
y2[x_] := y[x] /. sol
Dummy[ini_] := Module[{x0 = ini, result},
  result = FindMaximum[{y2[x], 5 < x < 10}, {x, 8}];
  result[[1]]
  ]
GetMemoryUse
data = Dummy[#] & /@ Range[5 10^2];
ClearMemory
Remove[data, sol]
GetMemoryUse
```

It takes 5-10 seconds to compile, and shows the memory usage before and after using a Module with FindMaximum in a cycle. As you can see, I have already played with HistoryLength and Clear[In, Out]; Protect[In, Out].

The problem seems to be with the interpolating function. When I fed an explicit function to FindMaximum, I found no memory leak.

How can this kind of memory leak resolved?

Cheers,
Zoltan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please report this as a bug. A minimal example:

```
Quiet @ Remove["System`Dump`rep$*"];
 Quiet @ Remove["System`Dump`rules$*"];
Quiet @ Remove["IPOPTLink`Private`monitor$*"];

if=NDSolveValue[{f'[x]==-2x+19,f[0]==4},f,{x,5,10}];
FindMaximum[{if[x], 5<x<10}, {x, 8}];

ToExpression[Names["System`Dump`rep$*"][[-1]], InputForm, DownValues]//Short

ToExpression[Names["System`Dump`rules$*"][[-1]], InputForm, OwnValues]//Short

ToExpression[Names["IPOPTLink`Private`monitor$*"][[-1]], InputForm, DownValues]//Short
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[System`Dump`rep$2694[System`Dump`m$_]]:>Module[{System`Dump`newm$},<<1>>]}
>
> {HoldPattern[System`Dump`rules$2694]:>{Compiler:>{Compile::cif,<<28>>,CompiledFunction::cftec},<<7>>}}
>
> {HoldPattern[IPOPTLink`Private`monitor$2659[{x14_}]]:>Null}
> ```

All of these temporary variables should have been removed when the associated [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module) was exited.

Comment: Thank you! I have submitted the bug report.